# SQL trigger to execute procedure and store new value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, procedure

I'm having an issue with calling a created procedure from a trigger. The procedure basically gets a ticket ref as `@sid` and a product id as `@pid`.

This is the procedure that I want to call:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calTicketPrice(@sid varchar, @pid varchar)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @productpvp INT;
    DECLARE @discount INT;

    SET @productpvp = (SELECT price FROM products WHERE products.barCode = @pid);
    SET @discount = (SELECT discount FROM products WHERE products.barcode = @pid);

    UPDATE sales 
    SET sales.total = @productpvp - (@productpvp * 0.18) + (@productpvp * @discount)
    WHERE sales.ticketRef = @sid;
END
RETURN
```

---

EDIT:

The tables are products and sales(atomic sale, just one product with a ticketref)
the values are products.price, products.discount sales.ticketref and sales.total.

When I insert one new sale i want to check all the sales and actualize the total price of the sales with the same ticket reference. So, the procedure works but i need to trigger it somehow. Please help.

This is not for a job, just for a practice.

---

So what I need is a trigger to execute this procedure passing the ticket reference and the product identifier **INSERTED**. I'm a newbie to SQL and I'm struggling with this even it could look a basic thing. I don't know how to work with the immediate inserted value.

Thanks in advance mates.

Comment: This does not sound like a good approach at all. Your trigger will have to do one of two things...and they are both bad. It will have to either call this with a scalar value assuming there is only ever 1 row inserted. This is a bad approach and one that should be avoided. To avoid that you will have to build a loop inside your trigger to call this procedure for each row that was inserted. Looping in sql server is very bad for performance. This whole process could probably be rethought so it works correctly and accuractely. We just need to know what your tables look like and and an explanation.

Comment: In addition to the bad practice of trying to bury business logic in a trigger (which has all sorts of bad problems), you're also not thinking in a set-based approach. Doing things like setting a variable from a table and then updating another table with that value - that shows procedural thinking and not SQL, set-based thinking. I would suggest that you read up on SQL a great deal if this is going to be part of your job or hire a good SQL developer if that's an option.